# UnicodeDecodeError when using a Python string handling function

Tags: python, unicode, internationalization

I'm doing this:

```
word.rstrip(s)
```

Where word and s are strings containing unicode characters.

I'm getting this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

There's a bug report where this error happens on some Windows Django systems. However, my situation seems unrelated to that case.

What could be the problem?

---

EDIT: The code is like this:

```
def Strip(word):
    for s in suffixes:
        return word.rstrip(s)
```

---

Comment: Show some more code - don't just tell us "`word` and `s` are strings containing unicode characters", show us an example that we can copy and paste into python and see it break. Also, what Python version is this? Strings and unicode behave very differently between Py2 and Py3.

Comment: what happens for `unicode.rstrip(word, s)`, if you're using py2.

Comment: @lvc: Firstly, I'm using Python 2. When I print the values of word and s, I see that they contain 'কিনেও' and 'ি' resp. This is just one example. They can contain various values. In this particular case, nothing should be stripped. unicode.rstrip(word, s) gives the same error. My code is as shown in the edit.

Comment: Edit extra information into the question, don't put it in comments where people can miss it. Also, http://bit.ly/unipain

Comment: Note that `rstrip` strips the *characters* from the end of a string in its parameter.  so `'aaabbbcccecb'.rstrip('ecb')` results in `'aaa'` NOT `'aaabbbccc'`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Thanks for that! I shouldn't be using rstrip at all then, since what I want is aaabbbccc!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `s` is a bytestring, while `word` is a unicode string - so, Python tries to turn `s` into a unicode string so that the `rstrip` makes sense. The issue is, it assumes `s` is encoded in ASCII, which it clearly isn't (since it contains a character outside the ASCII range).

So, since you intitialise it as a literal, it is very easy to turn it into a unicode string by putting a `u` in front of it:

```
suffixes = [u'ি']
```

Will work. As you add more suffixes, you'll need the `u` in front of all of them individually.

Comment: This is also one major benefit of moving to Py3 if you can. The equivalent code in Py3 is `'কিনেও'.rstrip(b'\xe0\xa6\xbf')` - and instead of trying to do the wrong thing and then complain that it doesn't work, it tells you `TypeError: rstrip arg must be None or str` which gives you a much better idea of how to fix it.

Comment: I can't move to Py3 at the moment because I'm using NLTK heavily, and that's still for Py2 only.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this happens because of implicit conversion in python2. 
It's explained in [this document](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#24), but I recommend you to read the [whole presentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) about handling unicode in python 2 and 3 (and why python3 is better ;-))

So, I think the solution to your problem would be to force the decoding of strings as utf8 before striping.

Something like :

```
def Strip(word):
    word = word.decode("utf8")
    for s in suffixes:
        return word.rstrip(s.decode("utf8")
```

Second try :

```
def Strip(word):
    if type(word) == str:
        word = word.decode("utf8")
    for s in suffixes:
        if type(s) == str:
            s = s.decode("utf8")
        return word.rstrip(s)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives the same error, this time on the first decode() call. Funny thing is, if I hard-wire a value of word into the code with word = 'কিনেও', then things work fine. But the code as in my post doesn't work, even though 'print word' gives 'কিনেও' (i.e. it has that value).

Comment: Can you give us the result of `type(word)` please ?

Comment: And `type(s)` when it breaks ?

Comment: @VelvetGhost how are you intialising `suffixes`?

Comment: suffixes = ['ি']. This is just one suffix obviously, but I intended to add many more to the list.

Comment: Ok can you try the second code sample ? I'm not sure it's right, because I'm mainly using python3, so it may need some fixes :-)

Comment: @VelvetGhost make that `[u'ি']` (ie, put a 'u' in front of the string literal). This will force it to be a unicode object, same as `word`, which will mean Python won't try to do strange things to make the `rstrip` make sense.

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'str' referenced before assignment!

Comment: Aha! using [u'ি'] worked! Thanks a lot lvc! Sorry it turned out to be a silly error after all.

Comment: Sorry, `str = str.decode("utf8")` should be `word = word.decode("utf8")`

Comment: @lvc can you "answer" so that we can upvote you, as your answer could be more exact than the one from Martijn Pieters ?